# How to solve "hot" hash key issue (space skewed data) in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hash, amazon-dynamodb, database, nosql

For example, I am using DynamoDB to store product purchase records. The hash key is **product ID** and the range key is **purchase time**.

Some popular products can have a lot of purchase records (**space skewed**) so that read/write requests can get throttled for "hot" partitions while other partitions are not using full throughput.

How to solve this problem and still be able to get latest purchase records? Thanks!

Comment: How many products do you have? Ideally, the partition key should have a large number of distinct values.

Comment: Partition key with a large number of distinct values does not solve this problem. Distinct hash key values do not mean uniformly distributed hotness.

Comment: Sorry - I don't follow. Best practice DynamoDB table design is that the partition key should have a large number of distinct values. If that's not the case you should reconsider your table design for best performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cache solution in order to achieve this.

You can follow the guidelines when designing a table to cache the popular items:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.CachePopularItems

My solution for this is to use elasticache (Redis), you can create a list that represent the last purchases per product and trim the last 100 purchases for each product, for example:

> LPUSH product:100 2016-08-13:purchaseId
>
> LTRIM product:100 0 99

Will trim the list to last 100 items.

I hope this help...